# Iterate over list selecting multiple elements at a time in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration, sequence

I have a list, from which I would like to iterate over slices of a certain length, overlapping each other by the largest amount possible, for example:

```
>>> seq = 'ABCDEF'
>>> [''.join(x) for x in zip(seq, seq[1:], seq[2:])]
['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF']
```

In other words, is there a shorthand for `zip(seq, seq[1:], seq[2:])` where you can specify the length of each sub-sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[seq[i:i+3] for i in range(len(seq)-2)]` is the Python code for something similar.

The far more elegant and recommended version of this is to use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library from Python (seriously, why do they not just include this function in the library?).

In this case, you would instead use something similar to the `pairwise` function provided in the documentation.

```
from itertools import tee
def tripletWise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1,s2), (s1,s2,s3), (s2,s3,s4), ..."
    a, b, c = tee(iterable, 3)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None)
    next(c, None)
    return zip(a, b)

[''.join(i) for i in tripletWise('ABCDEF')]
> ['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF']
```

You can also create a more general function to chunk the list into however many elements you want to select at a time.

```
def nWise(iterable, n=2):
    iterableList = tee(iterable, n)
    for i in range(len(iterableList)):
        for j in range(i):
            next(iterableList[i], None)
    return zip(*iterableList)

[''.join(i) for i in nWise('ABCDEF', 4)]
> ['ABCD', 'BCDE', 'CDEF']
```

Comment: `tripletWise` is wrong. It should return `zip(a, b, c)`

Answer (score 6):

Not an elegant solution, but this works:

```
seq = 'ABCDEF'
n=3
[seq[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq)+1-n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use grouper() in the itertools examples. Specifically `grouper(<iter>,3)`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Or, from the same page, another recommendation is installing more-itertools. Then you can use `ichunked()` or `chunked()`.

https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/